settings page in new Elementor's new add-on
I have created a settings page for my new Elementor plugin
But now I want to activate and deactivate my widgets by placing a select
But whatever command I use, this command is not recognized
can you help me ?
<?php 


function Galaxy_elementor_admin_menu(){
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'گلکسی المنتور' , 'Galaxy_Elementor'),
        __( 'گلکسی المنتور' , 'Galaxy_Elementor'),
        'manage_options',
        'myplugin_settings',
        'Galaxy_Elementor_plugin_template_callback',
        myplugin_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/img/0.png',
        10
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'myplugin_settings',
        __( 'ویجت ها' , 'Galaxy_Elementor'),
        __( 'ویجت ها' , 'Galaxy_Elementor'),
        'manage_options',
        'myplugin_subsettings',
        'Galaxy_Elementor_plugin_template_callback1',
        myplugin_PLUGIN_URL . 'assets/img/0.png',
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu' , 'Galaxy_elementor_admin_menu');


function Galaxy_Elementor_plugin_template_callback(){
    ?>
        <div class="mypluginset wrap">
            <h2 style="font-family: 'IranYekan';font-weight:900;">تنظیمات گلکسی المنتور</h2>
            <p>در این صفحه می توانید به راحتی ویجت هایی که میخواهید را فعال و ویجت هایی که نیاز ندارید را غیرفعال کنید تا وبسایت شما سبک تر فعالیت کند</p>
<style>
    .mypluginset{font-family: 'IranYekan';}
    .form-table tbody tr{float:right;width: 44%;margin:5px;border: 1px solid #ddd;background: #fff;padding: 0 5px;}
    .wp-core-ui select,.wp-core-ui select:hover,.wp-core-ui select:focus{color: #dc143c;border-color: #dc143c;}
    .wp-core-ui .button-primary,.wp-core-ui .button-primary:hover,.wp-core-ui .button-primary:focus{background:#dc143c;border-color:#dc143c;padding: 5px 15px;}
</style>

            <form action="options.php" method="post">
                <?php 
                    // security field
                    settings_fields('myplugin_settings');

                    // output settings section here
                    do_settings_sections('myplugin_settings');

                    // save setting button
                    submit_button( 'ذخیره تغییرات' );

                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php
}
function Galaxy_Elementor_plugin_template_callback1(){
    ?>
    <h4>تنظیمات ویجت ها </h4>
    <?php
}










// settings Template


function myplugin_settings_init(){

    // setup settings section
    add_settings_section(
        'myplugin_settings_section',
        'my plugin',
        '',
        'myplugin_settings',
    );











    // Register input select
    register_setting(
        'myplugin_settings',
        'myplugin_settings_select_field',
        array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
            'default' => ''
        )
    );
    // Add settings select
    add_settings_field(
        'myplugin_settings_select_field',
        __('active' , 'myplugin'),
        'myplugin_settings_select_field_callback',
        'myplugin_settings',
        'myplugin_settings_section',
    );







    

}
add_action('admin_init','myplugin_settings_init');





// settings select field template
function myplugin_settings_select_field_callback(){
    $myplugin_select_field = get_option('myplugin_settings_select_field');
    ?>
    <select name="myplugin_settings_select_field" class="regular-text" method="post">
        <option value="option1" <?php selected( 'option1' , $myplugin_select_field ); ?> >active</option>
        <option value="option2" <?php selected( 'option2' , $myplugin_select_field ); ?> >deactive</option>
    </select>
    <?php
}



Then I expected to be able to enable and disable my widget by putting the following code
But there was no result
        if ( isset( $GalaxyEl_select_field['option1'] ) ){
                printf( '', \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor_GA_bighead() ));
        }
            

Is there anyone who can help with this
I will be grateful
